# Интеграционное тестирование сервисов с тяжёлыми файлами

Tags: git, машинное-обучение, непрерывная-интеграция, devops

Подскажите, как вы решаете вопрос с интеграционниками сервисов/воркеров, в которых используются тяжёлые ml-модели (1GB)? Такие репозитории клонятся очень по долгу (пусть даже используется git-lfs или dvc). Например, такой репозиторий у нас клонится 10 минут. Каждый раз так ждать -- перебор.

Comment: Улучшить сеть, поставить ssd/nvme. Убрать прослойки (докер в докере в докере)

Comment: + к вышесказанному: Кэшировать у себя.